# Calling a function in useEffect until contract loaded

Tags: javascript, next.js, web3js

It works perfectly fine when I call  contract?.methods.name().call() in the same scope when loading providers. It works fine too when I do a page reload

However, if I call  contract?.methods.name().call() in another useEffect, it will cause an error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'methods') when I do a page reload. It seems this function is called when contract is not loaded yet or not available on the server side as I am using Next.js

How am I able to rectify this issue and still call contract?.methods.name().call() in another useEffect and do a page reload? Is that even possible? Below is my code. Thanks

```
const Demo = (props: Props) => {
  const [web3Api, setWeb3Api] = useState<{
    web3: Web3 | undefined;
    isProviderLoaded: boolean;
    provider: any;
    contract: any;
    name: string;
  }>({
    isProviderLoaded: false,
    web3: undefined,
    provider: undefined,
    contract: undefined,
    name: "",
  });
  const [contractName, setContractName] = useState<string>("");

  const loadProvider = async () => {
    const provider = await detectEthereumProvider();
    const web3 = new Web3(provider as any);

    if (provider) {
      const contract = await loadContract("Demo", web3);
      const name = await contract?.methods.name().call();
      setWeb3Api({
        web3,
        provider,
        contract,
        isProviderLoaded: true,
        name,
      });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getContractName = async () => {
      // todo Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'methods')
      const contractName = await web3Api.contract.methods.name().call();
      setContractName(contractName);
    };
    getContractName();
  }, [web3Api]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadProvider();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <p>Demo</p>
      {/* Work OK */}
      <p>{web3Api.name}</p>
      {/* Not OK */}
      <p>{contractName}</p>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Demo;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getContractName = async () => {
      const contractName = await web3Api.contract.methods.name().call();
      setContractName(contractName);
    };
    web3Api.contract && getContractName();
  }, [web3Api.contract]);
```